# Updating two image in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

Recently I find some bug while updating two image at a time. I use `if (!empty($_FILES['ngo_logo']['name']))` before first image and `elseif (!empty($_FILES['ngo_license_pic']['name']))` before second image.

Here is my full Controller Code:

```
function editProfile(){

    $ngo_id = $this->profile_model->editNgoProfile();

        /************* File Upload ************/
  if (!empty($_FILES['ngo_logo']['name'])) {


        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/ngo_logo/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx|zip|xls';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['remove_spaces']=true;
        $config['max_size']='10600';// in KB

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        $filetype = $_FILES['ngo_logo']['type'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['ngo_logo']['name'];

        if($filetype == "image/jpg")
                $file_type='jpg';
            else if ($filetype == "image/jpeg")
                $file_type='jpeg';
            else if ($filetype == "image/gif")
                $file_type='gif';
            else if($filetype == "image/jpeg")
                $file_type='jpg';

            else if($filetype == "image/pjpeg")
                $file_type='pjpeg';
            else if($filetype ==  "image/png")
                $file_type='png';

        $_FILES['ngo_logo']['name']=$ngo_id.'.'.$file_type;

        $this->upload->do_upload('ngo_logo');


        $up_dtat = array('ngo_logo' => $_FILES['ngo_logo']['name']);
        $this->db->where('ngo_id',$ngo_id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_ngo_users',$up_dtat);

   }


  elseif (!empty($_FILES['ngo_license_pic']['name'])) {


        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/ngo_license_pic/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx|zip|xls';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['remove_spaces']=true;
        $config['max_size']='10600';// in KB

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        $filetype = $_FILES['ngo_license_pic']['type'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['ngo_license_pic']['name'];

        if($filetype == "image/jpg")
                $file_type='jpg';
            else if ($filetype == "image/jpeg")
                $file_type='jpeg';
            else if ($filetype == "image/gif")
                $file_type='gif';
            else if($filetype == "image/jpeg")
                $file_type='jpg';

            else if($filetype == "image/pjpeg")
                $file_type='pjpeg';
            else if($filetype ==  "image/png")
                $file_type='png';

        $_FILES['ngo_license_pic']['name']=$ngo_id.'.'.$file_type;

        $this->upload->do_upload('ngo_license_pic');


        $up_dtat = array('ngo_license_pic' => $_FILES['ngo_license_pic']['name']);
        $this->db->where('ngo_id',$ngo_id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_ngo_users',$up_dtat);

 }
    redirect('NGO_Profile');

}
```

My problem is only first image will be update but another will not update. 
--> If I upload only one image then it will update and 
--> if i upload only first image then first image update 
--> in further time if i upload only second image then second image will update only...

**I need the proper solution actually what is the main reason for not update two image at a time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `elseif (!empty($_FILES['ngo_license_pic']['name'])) {` to `if(...)`

elseifs only trigger if A. the first if condition is false B. the elseif condition is true.

Comment: its working. but can't upload photo to different folder

Comment: Folder has to exist. Ci won't create it for you

Comment: make a new question with all the details is the best advice i can offer you right now

Comment: Okay but I have facing some problem to asking new question:

It says: **You have a history of asking low quality questions. Please put more thought, time, and effort into your questions. To help you do this, the number of questions you may ask per week is currently limited. For more information.**

Is this question is low quality questions??

Comment: dunno, i'm not a mod. maybe your past questions had downvotes/close votes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182912/discussion-between-alex-and-sabbir).